# Haskell: converting a list of tuples into a list of lists

Tags: list, haskell, tuples, data-conversion

I have a list of tuples:

```
  [("book", 1,0), ("book", 2,0), ("title", 2,1)]
```

that I wanted to convert into a list of lists with the ints converted to Strings as well:

```
[["book, "1","0"], ["book , "2", "0"]...]
```

I tried:

```
map(\(a, b, c) -> [a, b, c])myList
```

but I get the following error message:

```
* No instance for (Num [Char]) arising from a use of `myList'
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can not perform that conversion. Lists, unlike tuples are homogeneous: they contain values of the same type, only.

There's no such a list as `["book",1,0]`, since it contains both strings and numbers. That list can not have type `[String]`, nor type `[Int]`, for instance.

Comment: is there a way then to convert the ints inside the tuples into strings?

Comment: You can use `show` to convert an int to string, e.g. `map (\(a,b,c) -> [a,show b, show c])` but I'm unsure about why do you want to convert everything to string. A list of tuples is generally easier to work with than a list of lists of strings.

Answer (score 0):

In addition to @chi's answer, you may also try a sum of `Int` and `String`, called `Either Int String`.

```
concatMap
  (\(s, x, y) -> [Right s, Left x, Left y])
  [("book", 1, 0), ("book", 2, 0), ("title", 2, 1)]
= [Right "book", Left 1, Left 0, Right "book",
  Left 2, Left 0, Right "title", Left 2, Left 1]
```

If the numbers are to be associated with the string, however, the list of tuples is a superior structure.

Answer (score 0):

If you are sure that your tuple is of type `(String, Int, Int)` then you just write

```
tupleToList :: (String, Int, Int) -> [String]
tupleToList (a,b,c) = [a, show b, show c]
```

and map it over what you have, `[(String, Int, Int)]`.

More generally,

```
tupleToList :: (Show a, Show b) => (String, a, b) -> [String]
tupleToList (a,b,c) = [a, show b, show c]
```

which allows you to insert any displayable thing in 2nd and 3rd place of the input tuple, but not being *more general*: for example, you can not have

- Unfixed length of tuple, like `(a,b,c)` mixing with `(a,b,c,d)`
- Switching the `show` objects, like `(String, a, b)` mixing `(b, String, a)`

-- I mean, how would you store the different tuples in a list in the first place?

In case of that you really want, there is something called [Heterogenous list](https://wiki.haskell.org/Heterogenous_collections) which is never recommended and you cannot really get much out of it.